# Datepicker only changes date in first row of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

My datepicker only changes the date in the first row of the table.
I create one row of the table and then when a person clicks add, this row is cloned and appended to the table. The datepicker works after cloning but only changes value in the first row. This only happens when I destroy and deploy datepicker every time the row is cloned, otherwise the datepicker only works in the first row of my table.

Any help?

Thanks

HTML code

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tbody id="dp1412866353992">
      <input id="templateId" type="hidden" value="-1" name="templateId">
      <input id="isNew" type="hidden" value="true" name="isNew">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="periodIds" type="hidden" value="-1" name="periodIds">
          <input id="periodsNames" width="100%" type="string" value="q1" name="periodsNames">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="dp1412866353991" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" type="date" value="Thu Oct 09 15:52:33 BST 2014">
        </td>
        <td>
          <td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="periodIds" type="hidden" value="-1" name="periodIds">
          <input id="periodsNames" width="100%" type="string" value="q1" name="periodsNames">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="dp1412866353991" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" type="date" value="Thu Oct 09 15:52:33 BST 2014">
        </td>
        <td>
          <td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="periodIds" type="hidden" value="-1" name="periodIds">
          <input id="periodsNames" width="100%" type="string" value="q1" name="periodsNames">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="dp1412866353991" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" type="date" value="Thu Oct 09 15:52:33 BST 2014">
        </td>
        <td>
          <td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
$('#add-row').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //datepicker does not work witout being created and destroyed on each row.
    //$('.datepicker').datepicker('destroy');
    var tableBody = $('#periodsTable > tbody');
    var lastRowClone = $('tr:last-child', tableBody).clone();

    //setting periodId to -1 for any created periods
    $('td:first input[name=periodIds]', lastRowClone).val("-1");

    tableBody.append(lastRowClone);
    //$(".datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to fix the code so that it isn't halfway accross the page.

Comment: You can fix it just by removing blank spaces. Done that.

Comment: @Fionn - Do you have a lot of repeating ID's in this page?

Comment: IDs should be unique. Your _cloned_ element will have the same ID of its source. It's invalid markup and also will make jQuery selectors always point to the first occurrence in the page, ignoring the rest.

Comment: Ok but even when I remove the IDs (like I have in the code above) it still happens.

Comment: The dynamically added elements won't have the `DatePicker` attached to them. You need to use delegation.

Comment: You mean the datepicker class attached to them? I don't understand why they wouldn't if I cloned it, but even if I had the class "lastRowClone.find('input[type="date"]').addClass("datepicker")" it doesn't work...

Comment: In your `click` event handler, this would be the last line: `lastRowClone.datepicker();`

Comment: It's not about the element having the class `datepicker`, it's about the `DatePicker` widget not finding your elements because they were not in the page when you initiated it. Every new element added will need to have the `DatePicker` added to them. Got it?

Comment: Ok so you mean something like this? $(".datepicker").datepicker();

Comment: I've posted an answer. Hope you understand it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're initiating the `DatePicker` widget by adding it to the elements with `class` `datepicker`, it will work just on the elements that are part of the page on that moment.

For every other element added after this first call:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

Which happens in your `click` event handler, you need to add the `DatePicker` to them, even though they also have the `class` `datepicker`.
They're new elements in the page so:

```
$(function () {
    // Adding DatePicker to the elements already in the page.
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();

    $('#add-row').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var tableBody = $('#periodsTable > tbody');
        var lastRowClone = $('tr:last-child', tableBody).clone();

        //setting periodId to -1 for any created periods
        $('td:first input[name=periodIds]', lastRowClone).val("-1");

        tableBody.append(lastRowClone);

        // Adding DatePicker to the new element added to the page.
        // As the cloned element has the class hasDatepicker already there,
        // DatePicker thinks it's initialised for it.
        // You need to remove this class before adding DatePicker to it.
        lastRowClone.find('.datepicker').attr('id','').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
    });
});
```

**Note:** Like I mentioned in the comments, be aware of elements IDs to not get duplicated. Every ID in the page should be unique. Otherwise your markup will be invalid and any `jQuery` selector pointing to that ID will return just the first occurrence and will ignore the rest.

**Note 2:** Your `inputs` have `type` set to `date`. In modern browsers this will cause a conflict between the `HTML 5` native calendar and the `jQuery` `DatePicker` one.

**Note 3:** Your second `input` doesn't have the `class` `datepicker` set.

**Note 4:** Although you may not see any duplicated `ID` in your `HTML` markup, `DatePicker` gives the element a random `ID` when added to it, if the element doesn't have one. When you clone this element, you're creating a new element sharing this same `ID`, which will cause the `DatePicker` to always set the `Date` just in the first `input`. Find a way to give your elements proper and unique `IDs` to avoid this and many other issues.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/93nz5tx8/2/)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. Still only the first row works.

Comment: Can you remove the `JSP` bits of your question and post the rendered `HTML` markup, please?

Comment: I've just noticed that your `inputs` have `type` set to `date`. On modern browsers you'll have a conflict between the `HTML 5` native calendar and the `jQuery` `DatePicker`.

Comment: changed input to text but no luck, I have shown my html in the post above

Comment: Am looking at it now.

Comment: I've edited my answer. First mistake I left a comment in the code explaining it. The second mistake was that I forgot to look for the `input` in the cloned row to add the `DatePicker`.

Comment: Now every row has a datepicker but the datepicker for any row only changes the value in the top row.

Comment: Try: `.clone(false)` instead of just `.clone()` and tell me if it works. Also check if there are no duplicated `IDs` in your page.

Comment: I've added a bit to remove the cloned element `ID` as it was being duplicated. It's on you now to work out how to generate unique `IDs` for your elements.

Comment: .clone(false) doesn't work anyway, I'm fairly sure there are no duplicate Id's but I'll have a look..

Comment: `DatePicker` gives a random `ID` to the element if it doesn't have one. When you clone this element, you're obviously cloning its `ID` too. The solution is to have proper `IDs` set in your code.

Comment: Cheers it's working now, so I should give the datepickers ids and then change the id for each new one added in the on click event?

Answer (score 1):

After cloning give unique ids to your input fields. Then add datepicker to that input. And hope that this will solve your problem.

```
$("id").datepicker(); on click event or after cloning.
```