# In multiple rows of data, the datepicker only changes the first row of data

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, datepicker

I seem to have an odd problem with the jQuery UI Datepicker. If it's in a table with multiple rows of data, it changes the date in the first row even if the user clicks on the rows further down.

The view:

```
= form_tag bar_foo_path(@bar.id, @foo.id), id: "order-costs", method: :patch do |f|
  %table.table.table-bordered.table-select
    - @all_foos.each do |foo|
      %tr
        = fields_for "all_foos[]", foo do |p|
          %td= p.text_field :cf_date, value: formatted_date(foo.cf_date), maxlength: '10', placeholder: 'yyyy-mm-dd', class: 'save-data datepicker'
```

The JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  }).prop('readonly', true);
});
```

What's weird is that it only affects separate rows. If it has multiple datepickers in a row, the datepickers in that row work normally. It only affects like data in other rows.

Thoughts?

I've already looked at this answer:

[Datepicker only changes date in first row of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280445/datepicker-only-changes-date-in-first-row-of-table). This one involves adding the datepicker to rows added after the page is rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out the issue. When you use `fields_for` with the `text_field`, it will generate the input name based on both the `fields_for` and the `text_field` object name. In my case, since I had the `fields_for` use `all_foos[]`, it was generating an input with the name `all_foos__cf_date`. All of the inputs of that type had that name, and datepicker was simply filling in the first input with that name.

I fixed this by changing `all_foos[]` to `all_foos[#{foo.key}]`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use ...

```
f.fields_for :all_foos do |p|
  p.text_field(....)
```

Normally it should create inputs like `all_foos_0_cf_date, all_foos_1_cf_date`

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work. When I tried that, it created inputs like `all_foos[cf_date]`. I also tried converting the `form_tag` to `form_for`, and it created inputs like `foo[all_foos][cf_date]`. Maybe it's because of the rest of my code?